# Pairwise analysis of two groups transpoing dataframe using pivot_wider

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following dataframe

```
a <- 
structure(list(Sample_1 = structure(c(Bacteria_A = 1L, Bacteria_B = 2L, 
Bacteria_C = 3L, `4` = 1L, `5` = 2L, `6` = 2L, `7` = 3L, `8` = 1L
), .Label = c("12", "23", "25", "soil"), class = "factor"), Sample_2 = structure(c(Bacteria_A = 3L, 
Bacteria_B = 2L, Bacteria_C = 1L, `4` = 3L, `5` = 2L, `6` = 2L, 
`7` = 1L, `8` = 3L), .Label = c("10", "12", "23", "soil"), class = "factor"), 
    Sample_3 = structure(c(Bacteria_A = 2L, Bacteria_B = 1L, 
    Bacteria_C = 3L, `4` = 2L, `5` = 1L, `6` = 1L, `7` = 3L, 
    `8` = 2L), .Label = c("33", "45", "50", "soil"), class = "factor"), 
    Sample_4 = structure(c(Bacteria_A = 1L, Bacteria_B = 3L, 
    Bacteria_C = 2L, `4` = 1L, `5` = 3L, `6` = 3L, `7` = 2L, 
    `8` = 1L), .Label = c("32", "38", "44", "soil"), class = "factor"), 
    Sample_5 = structure(c(Bacteria_A = 2L, Bacteria_B = 3L, 
    Bacteria_C = 1L, `4` = 2L, `5` = 3L, `6` = 3L, `7` = 1L, 
    `8` = 2L), .Label = c(" 3", "34", "55", "soil"), class = "factor"), 
    Sample_6 = structure(c(Bacteria_A = 1L, Bacteria_B = 2L, 
    Bacteria_C = 3L, `4` = 1L, `5` = 2L, `6` = 2L, `7` = 3L, 
    `8` = 1L), .Label = c(" 0", " 3", "34", "soil"), class = "factor"), 
    Genus = c("Bacteria_A", "Bacteria_B", "Bacteria_C", "Bacteria_A", 
    "Bacteria_B", "Bacteria_B", "Bacteria_C", "Bacteria_A"), 
    Group = c("Soil", "Soil", "Soil", "Water", "Water", "Water", 
    "Water", "Water")), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")


> a
  Sample_1 Sample_2 Sample_3 Sample_4 Sample_5 Sample_6      Genus Group
1       12       23       45       32       34        0 Bacteria_A  Soil
2       23       12       33       44       55        3 Bacteria_B  Soil
3       25       10       50       38        3       34 Bacteria_C  Soil
4       12       23       45       32       34        0 Bacteria_A Water
5       23       12       33       44       55        3 Bacteria_B Water
6       23       12       33       44       55        3 Bacteria_B Water
7       25       10       50       38        3       34 Bacteria_C Water
8       12       23       45       32       34        0 Bacteria_A Water
```

I want to compare the treatment effect for each Bacteria in Soil vs Water. For exemple wilcox.test for BActeria_A in Soil vs Water. How can i do that ??

So far i have tried to pivot wider the dataframe to have bacteria as column names

```
 nms <- colnames(a)[1:(ncol(a)-2)]
> nms
[1] "Sample_1" "Sample_2" "Sample_3" "Sample_4" "Sample_5" "Sample_6"


    d <- a %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = Genus, values_from=nms )
       group_by(name) %>% 
      summarise(mean_Soil = mean(value[Group == "Soil"]), 
                mean_Water= mean(value[Group == "Water"]), 
                pvalue = wilcox.test(value ~ Group)$p.value) 


    Error in group_by(name) : object 'name' not found
```

The expected output would look something like this (fake values in this exemple). It is just to illustrate the desired output.

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   name       mean_soil mean_water pvalue
#>   <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Bacteria_A      24.3       24    0.936
#> 2 Bacteria_B      28.3       29    0.873
#> 3 Bacteria_C      26.7       23.8  0.748
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `pivot_longer` instead of `pivot_wider` since `summarise` works on columns. Then convert all values to numeric (they are factors in your example):

```
a_longer = 
  a %>%
  pivot_longer(c(-Genus,-Group)) %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(as.character(value)))
```

From here I would suggest to break the `summarise` in two parts since you are actually using two different groupings for `mean` and `wilcox.test`, then you can join the tables together:

```
full_join(
  a_longer %>% 
    group_by(Genus, Group) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Group, names_prefix = "mean_", values_from = mean)
  ,
  a_longer %>% 
    group_by(Genus) %>% 
    summarise(pvalue = wilcox.test(value ~ Group)$p.value)
)
```

Comment: Works great in the exemple above, thanks so much. However in my original dataset i get NA values for one column means. The first chunk of the full join that is returning the mean for every group return the correct values for one group but NA values for the other ?? Any idea ??

Comment: Sorry the NA values are for the bacteria that are only found in one group but not in the other

Comment: Is there a way to still run the wilcox.test when some mean are NA because missing bacteria ??? @tspano

Comment: The results of `wilcox.test` will all be shown if you use `full_join`, independently of `NA`s in the computation of `mean`